# Changing number of default segments in buffer tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-modeler, default-value, segment

The "Buffer" tool of QGIS by default uses five segments per quarter circle. I want to change this default value to e.g. 50, so I don't have to select and replace the current value every time I run the tool (which is quite often every day).

I dug around in a QGIS graphical model which runs the Buffer tool and found the following piece of "code":

```
    <Option name="SEGMENTS" type="List">
      <Option type="Map">
        <Option name="source" type="int" value="2"/>
        <Option name="static_value" type="int" value="80"/>
      </Option>
    </Option>
```

I suppose I need to change something somewhere in the enhanced properties dialogue. But frankly, I have no idea where to search, and what to set precisely.

Another possible place to change this setting could be to define custom environment variables in the system options tab of the properties dialogue. Yet again, I don't know how to set what.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

### Create a model

Create a model where you can choose an input vector layer and a numerical value for radius (buffer distance). In the algorithm creating the buffer, set a fixed value for the number of segments.

Save the model and from now on run the model (e.g. creating a shortcut) instead of the buffer tool.

Running the model, you'll get almost the same input dialog window as when using the native buffer tool, including options like copying as Python Command or as Batch Process:

[image]

There are at least two options for the algorithm to create buffers: QGIS native buffer tool or Geometry by expression.

#### Buffer tool

Create a model where you set a fixed value for the number of segments (like 20) in the buffer algorithm and create a numerical input for the buffer distance:

[image]

#### Geometry by expression

Use ["Geometry by Expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) to create buffers. Fill in the expression like this to get 200 segments for the whole circle:

```
buffer($geometry, @buffer_radius, 200)
```

[image]